Vue Import a configuration file
We have this code in the main.js to import configuration variables and make it available in the app
import * as config from '/config/settings.js'
app.config.globalProperties.apiUrl = config.apiUrl
app.config.globalProperties.imageBaseUrl = config.imageBaseUrl

and exclude the config/settings.js by setting it external in vite.config.js
Which work splendidly in production with the build version
If we run in a npm run dev local server however the import line is error-messaged as:

[vite] Internal server error: Cannot import non-asset file /config/settings.js which is inside /public. JS/CSS files inside /public are copied as-is on build and can only be referenced via  or  in html. If you want to get the URL of that file, use /config/settings.js?url instead.

If included in the index.html with`
    <script type="module" src="/config/settings.js"></script>

Before the inclusion of main.js the exports are not available.
How do make the import of external configuration work during development?
EDIT: Adding ?url to the link allows for debugging but than it doesn't work in production.

have you tried to use /config/settings.js?url instead like the message suggests?

@JaromandaX I was about to add that. It than works in dev but not in production
